# count multiple values from single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with customer information like date of birth, address, contactinfo, etc.

I want to count the number of customers per city with a single query that outputs two values per record, cityname and amount of customers living there:

```
Alabama 285
Kentucky 167
New York 4
Rio de Janeiro 950
etc...
```

There are hundreds of cities in the table so I can't do a

```
SELECT count(CASE WHEN city = 'Alabama' THEN 1 END) AS Alabama
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause to count the number of customers per city :

```
SELECT city
     , COUNT(*) 
FROM table 
GROUP BY city
```

Comment: Sometimes things are so simple you overthink it too much ... Thanks man!!